# Sound won't work with Soundblaster Audigy Fx PCIe card

Tags: drivers, 13.10, soundcard, sound-blaster, external-soundcard

To start, I am a complete linux noob trying out Ubuntu to see if I can use it as my primary OS. Perfectly willing to put work into getting it setup, but I'm running into an issue that I can't find a solution to. I've seen some similar questions asked but none with quite the same issue.

THE QUESTION: I installed a brand new copy of Ubuntu 13.10. I have a Soundblaster Audigy Fx Model SB1570 installed that works fine in Windows 7. Granted, it has a Windows 7 driver and I can't seem to find a Linux driver for said card. What can I do?

P.S. I have never messed with Linux before but I'm not a PC novice. And I know how to use google, it just hasn't helped me much here.

Comment: Please add the bit about the sound card(s) from `lspci -v`.

Answer (score 1):

After your system boots, and you verify that there is no sound, try these commands:

```
sudo pulseaudio -k
sudo modprobe -r snd_hda_intel
sudo modprobe snd_hda_intel
```

Then test to see if sound works. This sequence of commands makes my ALC898-based Audigy Fx PCIe card work normally for as long as the system is booted. If you find that these commands reliably make the card work, you might be able to put similar commands into a script in /etc/rc.local. This workaround is not ideal but is good enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Realtek ALC898 based sound card...
You'd better use the motherboard's integrated (probably very similar) codec.
Please see this: http://support.creative.com/kb/ShowArticle.aspx?sid=120331

Creative is not a real friend of an opensource community.
They've killed the Canadian Advanced Gravis Computer Technology and later the Aureal Semiconductor. Both companies was far better than Creative Labs those time.

There are no (working) windows like "drivers" for linux, we need the hardware specification to write kernel modules. Please ask Creative ;)

It may work somehow I think, but it's not a common card.

Some details may be handy like
`sudo lspci -vv`
`sudo lshw -class multimedia`
`aplay -l or aplay -L`